Can I Adjust Amount of Air Being Drawn in By Attic Air Handler?
I believe my air handler in my open-air attic is drawing more of the attic air than is needed, making the house much more expensive to heat/cool, as well as hard to keep dehumidified in wet Texas summers.
Is there a way to adjust this, or block off some of it?  I am thinking of how a vacuum often has a spot along the air-flow path that can be opened or closed to adjust the amount of suction at the tool end.






Why would an air handler ever need to draw air from an attic?  Are we talking about an attic used as finished living space?

Your AH shouldn't be drawing air from the attic, it should be drawing air from the interior of th house.

@Huesmann: to be clear, I am not talking about a return, but that these systems are typically (right?) built with fresh air exchange in mind.  Either way (as in whether designed for this or not), I am certain for several reasons/empirical evidence, that air from attic/outside is being drawn into system.

Please provide clear pictures of the fresh air inlet in your attic and /or outside source/s so we may be able to correctly determine what course you need to take.

@RMDman: I will but will need to wait until tomorrow as already to warm to go up right now.  You are talking about the (4-5)" metal tube that leads from air handler up through roof...correct?

If it's a furnace as well that tube is probably a vent for combustion gasses. Please provide the make and model number, plus some pictures. I strongly suspect if you're seeing air drawn in from the attic it's due to a leak rather than by design.

@RMDman: I've added pics to help clarify my question/situation.

@KMJ: Yes, you are correct...it's clear the tube is vent for furnace. Pics added.  Model is a Rheem...about 12 years old.  I forgot to check model, though :--(

That's a builder grade unit. It's not designed to do outdoor air exchange.

Thank you for adding the pictures.
That unit does not intentionally draw in air from the attic space. The design of this type of unit will draw in a small amount of unconditioned air from the surrounding space due to leaks in the cabinet. Some newer units make modifications to the design that cause the air leaks to be in to the unconditioned space rather than other way around.
Unless you locate a leak in the return ducting, reducing the amount of attic air that this unit takes in will almost certainly require replacement of the air handler.

An attempt could be made to tape/putty up leaks, but otherwise I agree with your assessment.
